# Twilio How to obtain trial number

Tags: twilio

how do I get a trial number? Do I click "buy" number?

The boss man signed up for the account in trail mode, and I don't want to hit buy if it is going to automatically bill him for stuff until we are sure/ready.

Is the "buy" hooked to the trial so it will stop working before a limit is reached? Which is what I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did mine, it was indeed hooked to the trial and only began billing once my trial had expired.